# Putting two pieces of code together to make it function

Tags: python, command-line

I have multiple pieces of code here and am having issues putting them together so my function will actually run.

I have a function:

```
def getGenes(spliced, infile, outfile):
```

that has an optional first parameter '-s', that when inputted by a user indicates a 'switch' calling for the 'spliced genes sequence. Therefore, I followed it with this (additionally, when run. sys.agrv[1] = spliced sys.argv[2] = infile and sys.argv[3] = outfile):

```
import sys
spliced = False
if '-s' in sys.argv:
    spliced = True
    infile, outfile = sys.argv[2:]
```

Now, whether or not the file contains the switch I want to write the following from the infile to the outfile:

```
fp = open(infile, 'r')
for line in fp:
    line = line.replace(',',' ')
    tokens = line.split()
    if '-s' in sys.argv and r:
        wp.write('>'+tokens[0]+'|'+tokens[1]+'('+tokens[2]+')'+':'+int(tokens[3])+'-'+int(tokens[4])+'|'+int(tokens[5])+'-'+int(tokens[10])+','+int(tokens[8])+'-'+int(tokens[11]))
    else:
        wp.write('>'+tokens[0]+'|'+tokens[1]+'('+tokens[2]+')'+':'+int(tokens[3])+'-'+int(tokens[4]))
```

the first statement should be written when the spliced parameter is given, the second (else part) should be written when the spliced parameter is not given). This code above creates the information line for the sequence that is to follow on the next line of the outfile.

Following this, depending on whether a line in the file contains a '+' or a '-' at a specific spot, another file is accessed to pull out a string at certain coordinates. This part that is taken out should be written directly under the corresponding line above. So, I should have a '+' and '-' part for both the spliced and unspliced parameters. I have the following code:

```
fp2 = open('chr22.fa', 'r')
for line in fp2:
    newstring = ''
    z = line.strip()
    newstring += z
for line in fp:
    fields = line.split('\t')
    gene_ID, chr, strand = fields[:2]
    start = int(fields[3])
    end = int(fields[4])
    bc = {'A': 'T', 'C': 'G', 'G': 'C', 'T': 'A', 'N':'N'}       
    if strand == '+':
        wp.write(newstring[start:end]) 
    if strand == '-':
        newstart, newend = -(start + 1), -(end + 1)
        wp.write(bc[base.upper()] for base in newstring[newstart:newend])
```

As you can see, I have it pick a different part out of the file depending on whether a '+' or a '-' is present. That said, I need to use this for both the spliced and unspliced options. But each line(or string) pulled from this file should be placed with its corresponding information line(created in the last piece of code). The code here is pulling a sequence from another file and translating it.

I need to put these two pieces of code together somehow so the format of my outfile has:

An information

Corresponding sequence

Another info line

Corresponding sequence

Comment: You should check out [the ``with`` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) for opening files, and [the ``argparse`` module](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) rather than working with ``sys.argv`` directly.

Comment: You better set a bounty on this or anyone isn't going to even bother reading this wall of text :P just my opinion, GL Or you could make a more resumed version... is all that information really needed to answer your question/problem? Maybe i'm just lazy today

Comment: Or if you're working with python2.6 or earlier (and are too lazy to download argparse to parse the commandline), optparse will work for this example too (although argparse is *WAY* better for many other tasks so I would probably recommend that one first)

Comment: What do you mean a bounty? No one will answer this? Ahhh, I need help!

Comment: I have not used argparse before and am unfamiliar with it

Comment: In code segments 2 and 3, what is `wp` ?  In segment 3, is the indentation correct if it is, what is the purpose of the first `for` loop?  It seems like you really only want the last line of the file which doesn't make sense to me -- also you could just do `z=line.strip()`

Comment: @Patrick Campbell Still, it would be better to get familiar with it, than re-inventing your own way of parsing command line arguments.

Comment: @PatrickCampbell [link to argparse documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html).  argparse is in the standard library (at least for later versions of python).  My philosophy is if there's a library that deals with what you're working with, you should probably learn it.  If it's in the standard library, you should definitely learn it.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do one, then the other, like so:

```
for line in fp:
  # Info line
  line = line.replace(',',' ')
  tokens = line.split()
  if '-s' in sys.argv and r:
    wp.write('>'+tokens[0]+'|'+tokens[1]+'('+tokens[2]+')'+':'+int(tokens[3])+'-'+int(tokens[4])+'|'+int(tokens[5])+'-'+int(tokens[10])+','+int(tokens[8])+'-'+int(tokens[11]))
  else:
    wp.write('>'+tokens[0]+'|'+tokens[1]+'('+tokens[2]+')'+':'+int(tokens[3])+'-'+int(tokens[4]))

  # Sequence line
  fields = line.split('\t')
  gene_ID, chr, strand = fields[:2]
  start = int(fields[3])
  end = int(fields[4])
  bc = {'A': 'T', 'C': 'G', 'G': 'C', 'T': 'A', 'N':'N'}       
  if strand == '+':
    wp.write(newstring[start:end]) 
  if strand == '-':
    newstart, newend = -(start + 1), -(end + 1)
    wp.write(bc[base.upper()] for base in newstring[newstart:newend])
```

Or am I missing something here?